# why jquery ajax prevent loading another url page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After `$.ajax` request, i cannot load other page on new tab in browser. **what is the reason?**

my javascript code in this url `https://example.com/page1.php`:

```
$('#myButton').on("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
                url: "models/data.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {...},
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                     //...
                },
                error: function (asd, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     //...
                }

            });
});
```

after click on `myButton` i cannot load another url in other tabs, As long as the ajax request ends. for example `https://example.com/page2.php` **what is the reason?**

Comment: If the pages use PHP sessions, there's a lock that prevents multiple pages from modifying the session at a time. So the second script will be blocked until the first script finishes.

Comment: @Barmar yes exactly right. my pages use PHP sessions. is possible use multiple script on one session same time and how?

Comment: Use `session_write_close()` to unlock the session.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much for the precise and short answer